# describe limitation of a user about general action in use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

In an use case I have two Actor/user:

1. Patient
2. Expert

Both of them can do **create/view/edit** on patient profile. Expert can do them on all profiles,but patient can effect only on him/her profile.

I have to keep diagram clear and avoid from repeating the same things. Now I want to know is there a way to draw **create/view/edit** once but describe patient's limitations? Or it may be my mistake and it is better to use another diagram to describe limitations of actors? Sorry,but I am new by UML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UML Use Case diagram there is (as far as I know) no built-in way to visually capture constraints. You can show then using the invaluable note symbol:

[image]

Although you can model the access right policies using some simple means:

[image]

realistic user access rights management will be probably implemented using access tokens, authentication, authorization and all this stuff delegated to another (complex and reliable) system component providing some kind of `CanAccess(who, what, CRUD): boolean` service to the "*system*".

In order to capture the various limitations you would typically put them into the `precondition` part of the [Wikipedia: Use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Fully_dressed) narrative.

In the `UML` model the limitations would map to [constraints](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html) and `guard` conditions shown in the behavior diagrams describing the use case.

See also:

- chapter "Describing Use Case Behaviors" in [uml-diagrams.org: UML Use Case](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html)

Comment: Thank you.I accept it and +1 for your attention and times.

Comment: @hasanghaforian You are welcome. Let's hope it will be useful also to some future reader. BTW: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272940/why-is-thanking-discouraged-in-comments

Comment: There isn't a formal constraint mechanism built into the UseCase class, except in the case of Extends.  Your informal solution is the one I would use, too.  If a formal solution were needed, one could always create a "UseCaseConstraint" stereotype.  I've seen "OR" joined by dotted lines fairly often in descriptions of use case diagram syntax although I can't find any reference to it in the spec.  So, that might be an example of a particular constraint stereotype that some people like to use.

Comment: @BobRodes you can find example of the dotted line notation in [www.omg.org: UML/2.4.1/Superstructure](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF/) as "Figure 7.34 - {xor} constraint" and in [www.omg.org: UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/) as "Figure 7.16 shows an {xor} constraint between two associations"

Comment: @xmojmr Yeah, it's certainly one of the constraint notations, but there isn't anything in the spec that sets it up for use cases--or any other means of formally expressing constraints--that I can see.  I've been looking at the use case metamodel (superstructure 2.4.1, fig. 16.2) which shows that constraints are only formally defined for the Extend metaclass.

Comment: @BobRodes these snippets from superstructure 2.4.1 "_In general there are many possible kinds of owners for a Constraint. The only restriction is that the owning element must have access to the constrainedElements_" and "_For a Constraint that applies to two elements (such as two classes or two associations), the constraint may be shown as a dashed line between the elements_" and "_Element is an abstract metaclass with no superclass. It is used as the common superclass for all metaclasses in the infrastructure library_" seem to say that constraint can be attached to anything including UseCase

Comment: That's a good find!  It got me wandering around in the "abstract syntax" diagrams.  Now I believe this logic applies: 1. Elements can own other elements (7.3.14); 2. Constraints are associated with Elements via a constrainedElement property (Fig 7.7); 3. Namespaces have a composition association with Constraints via an ownedRule property (ibid.); 4. Classifiers are Namespaces (Fig 7.9); 5. UseCases are Classifiers (Fig 16.2).  Therefore, UseCases can use constraints in the same way that any other class can.  Ok, I've convinced myself.  I can now see the formal means.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just to be clear, I take back my statement in my first note that there isn't a formal constraint mechanism built into the UseCase class.  I now find that the mechanism is derivable from its generalizations.  (Addendum to my previous note: Classes are also Classifiers).

Comment: @BobRodes thanks for showing the reasoning chain. It is a good example of **1)** why Stack Overflow answers formed as "_read the ~700 pages long UML specification, it is all there_" are often not very helpful without further references and **2)** why opinion-based answers without any references are not useful at all and **3)** why the UML 2.5 seems to aim to be shorter and clearer and **4)** why I prefer to use [Kirill Fakhroutdinov's hyperlinked digestible UML explanation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/about.html) as first stop

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that you quote that site a good deal, and I like it too.  I use Tom Pender's UML Bible as my "primary secondary reference", partly because I got started in UML by taking one of his classes, and partly because he invited me to "really learn UML" by working as a tech editor on the book.  He got me in the habit of looking things up in the spec, in part by pointing out things in popular UML books that *weren't* in the spec.  So, I start out skeptical when I see sites like Kirill's, and see what I find.  In his case, it looks like he's as conscientious as they come.  Good site.

Answer (score 2):

A use case diagram is not meant to show the permissions that each actor has to perform particular operations. It is meant to show what the system has to do and who it has to do it for.

In this case, I'd say you have only one kind of actor for this use case diagram: User. And you have the use cases: "User Creates/views/edits".

The exception would be if the Create operation of an Expert is different from that of a Patient (in a way that would be visible on the use case diagram). For instance, if "Expert Creates" also has to perform "Expert Sends Email", then that would be a reason to consider two separate actors.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.A question arises:Which  diagram or documentation tool is capable to describe actor's limitation?

Comment: There's none in particular. A spreadsheet would work as well as anything.

Comment: @xmojmr OK! Please add your comment as answer.

Comment: It seems that xmojmr's answer is better.But +1 for your attention and times.

Comment: While I take the point you make in your first sentence, I also think it can be useful to capture constraint information in a use case context.  While you can always theoretically capture it in related diagrams, I see practical value in being able to put it here so viewers don't have to go digging around for it.